# How to handle an error in CV2(Cv2.imwrite)?

Tags: python, python-3.x, error-handling, opencv

I am trying to take care of an error that cv2.imwrite keeps throwing, it keeps reaching the exact same image in a folder and then saying "-215:Assertion failed" at the cv2.imwrite line and I am not having much luck writing fail safes for that type of error, it is reading correctly so I have no idea why it wont write.
I have tried these two methods:

```
        writeStatus = cv2.imwrite('output/'+ i, cropped)
        if writeStatus is True:
            print('Image Written')
        else:
            print('Error saving photo')
            cv2.imwrite('rejected/'+ i, image)
```

```
        if cv2.imwrite('output/'+ i, cropped) == True:
            print('Image write succeeded')
        else:
            if cv2.imwrite('rejected/'+ i, image)== True:
                print ('Cropped image could not be written, sent to rejects')
            else:
                print('writing error, script stopped')
                break
```

I have no idea why it wont save the image, it seems to hate only this particular one so far, even if the image is alone in a folder it wont write it, I honesty dont care as long as I can output images like that to the reject folder instead of it killing the whole script.
**EDIT** I tried using

```
        writeStatus = cv2.imwrite('output/'+ i, cropped)
        if writeStatus is True:
            print('Image Written')
        else:
            print('Error saving photo')
            continue
```

and the error still stopped the script

Comment: you're trying to save an empty image. Check why "cropped" is empty

Comment: I have no idea why its empty, it handles the image fine until it gets to the imwrite command. Nothing should be returning None values from what I can tell.

Comment: @Miki I added a check to make sure the crop values were not None or 0 and they were fine, went right past the check then threw the same error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***Suggestion#1***

---

If we look at the statement:

```
writeStatus = cv2.imwrite('output/'+ i, cropped)
```

`'output/' + i` supposed to be image name and cropped should be an image.

From what I understand, you want to save `i`th value, but the correct way is:

```
from os.path import join

filename = join('output', str(i) + '.png') # you can use other extensions like .jpg
cv2.imwrite(filename, cropped)
```

But, this is true if `cropped` variable is an image.

***Suggestion #2***

---

If a single image is causing a problem and you don't care, you could use `try-except` block and `continue` keyword

```
try:
    writeStatus = cv2.imwrite(...)
    .
    .
except:
    continue
```

Comment: Why would this cause an error on only one image though? All the other images work fine. output/ is the filepath, I have the original file name stored in variable i.

Comment: Only for a single image? then you can use `continue` keyword to skip the image.

Comment: Tried using the continue keyword with the writeStatus so that if writeStatus was false it would trigger the continue, no luck, the error still stopped the script.

Comment: I've updated my answer, please look at the ***Suggestion#2*** part

Comment: Ok, that works, I added the function to output the problem image to a separate folder and it worked like a charm. Not sure why the true false statement doesn't work, from what I can tell cv2.imwrite should output true or false because the print image written function works if its true. Its a mystery to me.